# Decompress async-http-client gzipped HttpResponseBodyPart in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, http, gzip, scala-dispatch

Because Scala Dispatch 0.9.5 doesn't seem to have a default handler for decompressing GZIP streams, I'm attempting to modify it's `as.stream.Lines` handler for incoming data. Since the same project is also using Spray.io, I attempted to use it's `GzipDecompressor` on the `HttpResponseBodyPart` bytes, but it threw an exception. See below:

```
def onBodyPartReceived(bodyPart: HttpResponseBodyPart) = {
    if (state == CONTINUE) {
      val decomp = new GzipDecompressor
      val bytes = decomp.decompress( bodyPart.getBodyPartBytes )
      onString(new String(bytes, charset))
    }
    state
  }
```

The method above modifies the following (line 23): https://github.com/dispatch/reboot/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/stream/strings.scala#L23

It throws an exception! `java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format` For those wondering what GzipDecompressor looks like, here it is: https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-httpx/src/main/scala/spray/httpx/encoding/Gzip.scala

I know that it is indeed a Gzipped stream. Any workarounds? Thanks!

### Update

Playing around with the following:

```
  val machine = new GZIPDecompressMachine
  val bytes = machine.write( bodyPart.getBodyPartBytes )
  onString(machine.stop().flatMap((a) => a).mkString)
```

The class `GZIPDecompressMachine` comes from here: https://gist.github.com/841435/09921c8dcbb6b2ad01a3161589ed4fe68f256fbc

It's throwing an exception: `java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream` any ideas here?

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this issue?

Comment: @gerasalus Negative, though haven't looked through Dispatch 0.11 yet. Temporarily I am using low-level Java APIs to handle the connection in the meantime.